ActiveCollab API - How to get tasks dependencies ids?
I am currently working on an integration. So far everything looks good since I am able to get most of the information needed from the tasks while using the path:
projects/project_id/tasks/taskd_id
as follows:
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$authenticator= new \ActiveCollab\SDK\Authenticator\Cloud(
    'MyCompany',
    'MyApp',
    '**username**',
    '**password**'
);  

$token= $authenticator->issueToken(183704);
if ($token instanceof \ActiveCollab\SDK\TokenInterface) {
    $ac_obj= new \ActiveCollab\SDK\Client($token);
}

$projectId= 123;
$taskId= 45678;

$objURL_tasks= "projects/".$projectId."/tasks/".$taskId;
$tasks_json_response= $ac_obj->get($objURL_tasks)->getJson();

print_r($tasks_json_response);

?>

but I noticed that for task's dependencies I am only getting a count, not the ids:
            [open_dependencies] => Array
                (
                    [parents_count] => 0
                    [children_count] => 0
                )

I was not able to find any path related to dependencies on:
https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/index.html
I also tried using paths like:
projects/project_id/tasks/taskd_id/dependencies
projects/project_id/tasks/taskd_id/open_dependencies
but not luck there.
Is there any way of getting this information (dependencies ids) from the API?
Thanks in advance!
Kind Regards.
